# Solving $\int_0^{\sqrt 6} \left(\frac{t^4}{390}-\frac{t^2}{6}+1\right)^p\;dt.$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, hypergeometric-function

I am having trouble evaluating the following integral for $0<t<\sqrt 6$ and $p>1$:

$$\int_0^{\sqrt 6} \left(\frac{t^4}{390}-\frac{t^2}{6}+1\right)^p\;dt.$$

Which substitution would work here?

Comment: Nothing pleasant unfortunately. If $p$ is a positive integer we can expand and integrate term by term. If $p$ is not an integer, we don't even have that, and should use a numerical method.

Comment: [cross posting](http://mymathforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=25875)

Comment: If $p$ is a half-integer, your integral is expressible in terms of the elliptic integrals.

Comment: It quite depends on p.

Comment: Start simplifying it to $$ \left(\left(\frac{t^2}{12}+1 \right)^2 - \left(\frac{t^2}{12}\frac{\sqrt{41}}{\sqrt{65}}\right)^2\right)^p $$

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\int_0^{\root{6}}\pars{{t^{4} \over 390} - {t^{2} \over 6} + 1}^{p}\,\dd t:\
     {\large ?}.\quad p > 1.\quad}$ Note that $\ds{\root{6} \approx 2.4495}$.

> \begin{align}
> &\int_0^{\root{6}}\pars{{t^{4} \over 390} - {t^{2} \over 6} + 1}^{p}\,\dd t
> ={1 \over 390^{p}}\int_0^{\root{6}}\pars{t^{4} - 65t^{2} + 390}^{p}\,\dd t
> \\[3mm]&={1 \over 390^{p}}
> \int_0^{\root{6}}\bracks{\pars{\mu^{2} - t^{2}}\pars{\nu^{2} - t^{2}}}^{p}\,\dd t
> \tag{1}
> \\[3mm]&\mbox{where}\quad
> \left\lbrace%
> \begin{array}{rclclcl}
> \mu & \equiv & \root{\half\pars{65 - \root{2665}}} & \approx & 2.5862 & > & \root{6}
> \\[1mm]
> \nu & \equiv & \root{\half\pars{65 + \root{2665}}} & \approx & 7.6362 & > & \root{6}
> \\[2mm]
> &&{\mbox{Note that}\ \mu\nu = \root{390}}&&&&
> \end{array}\right.
> \end{align}

Expression $\pars{1}$ is reduced to:
\begin{align}
&\int_0^{\root{6}}\pars{{t^{4} \over 390} - {t^{2} \over 6} + 1}^{p}\,\dd t
=\int_{0}^{\root{6}}\pars{1 - {t^{2} \over \mu^{2}}}^{p}
\pars{1 - {t^{2} \over \nu^{2}}}^{p}\,\dd t
\\[3mm]&=\int_{0}^{6}\pars{1 - {t \over \mu^{2}}}^{p}
\pars{1 - {t \over \nu^{2}}}^{p}\,\pars{\half\,t^{-1/2}\dd t}
\\[3mm]&=\half\root{6}\int_{0}^{1}t^{-1/2}\pars{1 - {6 \over \mu^{2}}\,t}^{p}
\pars{1 - {6 \over \nu^{2}}\,t}^{p}\,\dd t
\end{align}
The result is related to the [Appell Hypergeometric Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appell_hypergeometric_series). In order to show clearly that relation we rewrite the above result as:
\begin{align}
&\int_0^{\root{6}}\pars{{t^{4} \over 390} - {t^{2} \over 6} + 1}^{p}\,\dd t
\\[3mm]&=\root{6}\times
\\[3mm]&\bracks{%
\overbrace{{\Gamma\pars{\color{#00f}{3/2}} \over
        \Gamma\pars{\color{#c00000}{1/2}}
        \Gamma\pars{\color{#00f}{3/2} - \color{#c00000}{1/2}}}}^{\ds{=\ \half}}\
\int_{0}^{1}t^{\color{#c00000}{1/2} - 1}\
\overbrace{\pars{1 - t}^{\color{#00f}{3/2} - \color{#c00000}{1/2} - 1}}^{\ds{=\ 1}}
\pars{1 - {6 \over \mu^{2}}\,t}^{-\pars{-p}}
\pars{1 - {6 \over \nu^{2}}\,t}^{-\pars{-p}}\!\!\!\!\!\dd t}
\\[3mm]&=\root{6}\
{\rm F}_{1}\pars{%
\color{#c00000}{\half},-p,-p,\color{#00f}{3 \over 2},{6 \over \mu^{2}},
{6 \over \nu^{2}}}
\end{align}
$\ds{{\rm F}_{1}}$ is an [Appell Hypergeometric Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appell_hypergeometric_series).
$$
\mbox{As}\quad
{6 \over \mu^{2}} = {1 \over 130}\,\pars{65 + \root{2665}}
\quad\mbox{and}\quad {6 \over \nu^{2}} = {12 \over 65 + \root{2665}}
$$

> \begin{align}&\color{#00f}{\large%
> \int_0^{\root{6}}\pars{{t^{4} \over 390} - {t^{2} \over 6} + 1}^{p}\,\dd t}
> \\[3mm]&=
> \color{#00f}{\large\root{6}
> {\rm F}_{1}\pars{
> \half,-p,-p,{3 \over 2},{65 + \root{2665} \over 130},
> {12 \over 65 + \root{2665}}}}\,,\qquad\qquad p > 1
> \end{align}